# Manually Authorize User in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am looking to manually authorize a user knowing the username. This account however, has no password. It is an account created with an association to a Twitter account in another table. I can verify that the correct twitter account is trying to sign in, but I need to be able to use the Auth component to authorize the user linked to this twitter account.

All accounts that are linked to a twitter account are created in the same fashion, without a password. Since we are planning to make changes to improve this later, a generic password is not a viable option - we need to authenticate the user regardless of what is (or isn't) in the password field of the users table.

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but I still had problems with it. The end result that worked was to send an array that contained the id, hashed password, and name. Failing to pass the name resulted in logging in a user with no name. Failing to send the password produced a warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose by "authorize" you mean "authenticate" or "log in". That's as simple as passing the primary id of the user record to `Auth::login()`:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('twitter_id' => ...)));
$this->Auth->login($user['User']['id']);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Worked like a charm. Thanks :D

Comment: I have tried the above solution, the application seems loging in, but i am not able to fetch anything with
     $this->Auth->user();
like role, username, id. I get following error
 Argument 1 passed to Hash::get() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/xyzz/public_html/Lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php on line 668. As per stack trace it is triggering where i am calling     $this->Auth->user('role');

Answer (score 3):

Cake 2.3 + apparently requires this to now be in an array in order to work properly:

```
$this->Auth->login(array('id' =>$user['User']['id']));
```

It did not work just passing the id as a single integer.

Comment: Actually, the flat User array: `$this->Auth->login($user['User']);` Otherwise you are forgetting/missing the other information - which can be vital (like roles, username etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Auth->login($user['User']['id']);
$this->Auth->login($user['User']['username']);
$this->Auth->login($user['User']['password']);  // hashed password
```

Comment: Please give enough information about this code.